# Grep to search directories for patterns inside a text file

Tags: linux, command-line, grep

I have a file where it contains a list of search patterns (`searchPattern.txt`). Its contents is similar to the contents below where there are 3000+ of them.

```
123456
234567
345678
.
.
.
```

What I wanted to do is to use `grep` and search directories using the patterns listed in the file if they exist. It would be similar to this kind of command but instead of one search string there are many and its listed in a file.

```
grep searchPattern.txt diagnostics*
```

Although the command above doesn't work its just an idea as to what I wanted to happen.
Can this be done with `grep`? If it can't be done can someone suggest a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
grep -r -f /path/to/pattern/file diagnostics*
```

Comment: hi tink this one doesn't work.

Comment: @dimas: maybe I didn't quite understand your question: you have a file with multiple patterns that you would like to search for in a directory structure where each directory is named diagnostics{something-or-other}? Or are you trying to find files under the directory whose name contains a pattern?

Comment: Yup the first one.

Comment: @dimas have you checked with `find` and `xargs` ?

Comment: So in what way is grep -f failing?

Comment: it didn't found anything... I made sure that in the file there are 2 numbers that can be found in diagnostic directories (plural) using grep -e '123456\|234567' diagnostic* this works but using ur solution i didn't found any of the numbers

Comment: @dimas you want to search in file ? `diagnostic` is a file ?

Comment: hi Rahul diagnostic is a directory and it contains files. There are many diagnostic directories that's why I placed diagnostic*.

Comment: So mainly you want to search in `diagnostic/file`  m I right ?

Comment: @dimas then add `-r` to the `grep`.

Comment: yes I want to search all the files in diagnostic1/file(s), diagnostic2/file(s)... etc

Answer (score 1):

This is probably work with all linux variants:

```
$ grep -rFf searchPattern.txt directory/
```